# Loading preload script in Electron and Vue

Tags: vue.js, electron, vue-cli-3, electron-builder

I am using Vue CLI 3 and `vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder` to package my Vue Electron app and I am not able to get my preload.js script for electron working.

**main window**

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: false,
    preload: path.join(__dirname, "/../src/preload.js") // works but window.electron.dialog in undefined
  }
});
```

**preload.js**

```
const { dialog } = require("electron");

window.electron = {};
window.electron.dialog = dialog;
```

The `window.electron.dialog` is always undefined in my Vue component - the import is clearly not working. Note that `window.electron` is defined properly. I must be missing something.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following lines into the file `vue.config.js` , if the file does not exist create one in the root folder of your project

```
module.exports = {
 //...
 pluginOptions: {
  electronBuilder: {
    preload: 'src/preload.js',
    // Or, for multiple preload files:
    // preload: { preload: 'src/preload.js', otherPreload: 'src/preload2.js' }
  }
 }
 //...
}
```

Check the documentation for more [#preload-files](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/guide.html#preload-files)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was more simple than expected. Imports work in `window.onload` event.

```
window.onload = () => {
  const { dialog } = require("electron").remote;

  window.electron = {};
  window.electron.dialog = dialog; // now set properly
};
```

Comment: I still can't get this to work... require("electron") returns undefined here.