# import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron' produces this error: __dirname is not defined

Tags: vue.js, webpack, electron, webpack.config.js, ipcrenderer

With this simple vue page:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron'

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  data() {
    return {
      dato: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    rendererFunct () {
      //ipcRenderer.on('setting', (event, arg) => {
        //console.log(arg);
      //})
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The only presence of import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron' produces the  error  __dirname is not defined :

[image]

Is this problem is something related to webpack configuration or it is due to something else?

This is my webpack.config.js  :

```
import 'script-loader!./script.js';
import webpack from 'webpack';

const path = require('path');

const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  target: ['electron-renderer', 'electron-main', 'electron-preload'],
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      chainWebpackMainProcess: config => {
        config.resolve.alias.set('jsbi', path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jsbi/dist/jsbi-cjs.js'));
      }
    },
  },
};

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/background.js',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'backend.js'
  }
}

module.exports = config => {
  config.target = "electron-renderer";
  return config;
};

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: 'source', to: 'dest' },
        { from: 'other', to: 'public' },
      ],
      options: {
        concurrency: 100,
      },
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          'style-loader',
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};

const supportedLocales = ['en-US', 'it'];

export default const config = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /date\-fns[\/\\]/,
      new RegExp(`[/\\\\\](${supportedLocales.join('|')})[/\\\\\]index\.js$`)
    )
  ]
}
```

This is vue.config.js :

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    // Configuration applied to all builds
  },
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      chainWebpackMainProcess: (config) => {
        // Chain webpack config for electron main process only
      },
      chainWebpackRendererProcess: (config) => {
        config.plugin('define').tap((args) => {
          args[0]['IS_ELECTRON'] = true
          return args
        })
      },
      mainProcessFile: 'src/background.js',
      mainProcessWatch: ['src/preload.js'],
    }
  }
}

module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      disableMainProcessTypescript: false,
      mainProcessTypeChecking: false
    }
  }
}
```

- Electron: version 9.0.0
- webpack: version 4.44.1
- System:
  OS: Linux 5.4 Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
  CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz
- Binaries:
  Node: 14.5.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/node
  Yarn: 1.22.4 - /usr/bin/yarn
  npm: 6.14.5 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/npm
- Browsers:
  Chrome: 84.0.4147.105
  Firefox: 79.0

Looking forward to your kind help.
Marco

Comment: if you have found a solution, it is always nice to post this so other people can find it. Have you had any progress on this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import ipcRenderer in vue.js ? \_\_dirname is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63615355/how-to-import-ipcrenderer-in-vue-js-dirname-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

__dirname is a NodeJS variable, in recent electron versions, node integration is disabled by default. When opening your BrowserWindow, you should add the following to the options:

```
webpreferences:{
    nodeIntegration: true
}
```

This is however **STRONGLY DISCOURAGED** as this opens up security issues.

this seems to solve it for most people (for me sadly enough i now get the next error:
`fs.existsSync is not a function`)

a better solution i to change your bundler to the correct build mode. You should not be building for node but for web, so target:esnext or something.

if something requires node access, this should be solved by running it in the background thread or the preload scripts.

Comment: Downvoted because it is irresponsible to blindly recommend `nodeIntegration: true`.  Due to security concerns, the electron developers [strongly discourage](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920#issuecomment-575839738) enabling `nodeIntegration`.  See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66035397/1444650) for a history.

Comment: @BenjaminBray i completely agree, i slightly updated my answer, but it is still not good, i encourage you to update my answer to contain your links

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the solution described on this post
[How to import ipcRenderer in vue.js ? __dirname is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63615355/how-to-import-ipcrenderer-in-vue-js-dirname-is-not-defined)

In this way you can call this method from vue files:

```
window.ipcRenderer.send(channel, args...)
```

Just make sure you configure preload.js on vue.config.js:

```
// vue.config.js - project root
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
       preload: 'src/preload.js'  //make sure you have this line added
    }
  }
}
```